# SQL Server- SQL Replace on all columns in all tables across an entire DB

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a long shot and I'm guessing there is no easy answer for this but...
I've inherited a database which is populated with some terrible data. Many lines containing descriptions have carriage return characters in meaning that when we BCP the data out, it takes the carriage returns with it.

My question: 
Is there a way to do a global replace across an entire database in MS SQL Server? The database contains hundreds of tables so performing this table by table could prove very time consuming.

Any hints or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance. 
Pete.

Comment: can't you remove the unwanted characters during your BCP ?

Comment: Thanks Thomas. This may well be possible but I was hoping there may be a way of cleaning the data up at the source. 
if I can't find a way then I will certainly look down that route. 
Thanks for the inspiration.

Comment: You could write a solution that queries the meta-tables/views and generates dynamic SQL updates.

Comment: be careful if you have any application based on timestamp / CDC and if your database is big, because you'll update your entire database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to do a find and replace across your entire DB. If so, [try this script from MSSQLTIPS](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1555/sql-server-find-and-replace-values-in-all-tables-and-all-text-columns/). It does exactly that.

Here is the complete script:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @stringToFind VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @stringToReplace VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @schema sysname
DECLARE @table sysname
DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @sqlCommand VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @where VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @columnName sysname
DECLARE @object_id INT

SET @stringToFind = 'Smith'
SET @stringToReplace = 'Jones'

DECLARE TAB_CURSOR CURSOR  FOR
SELECT   B.NAME      AS SCHEMANAME,
         A.NAME      AS TABLENAME,
         A.OBJECT_ID
FROM     sys.objects A
         INNER JOIN sys.schemas B
           ON A.SCHEMA_ID = B.SCHEMA_ID
WHERE    TYPE = 'U'
ORDER BY 1

OPEN TAB_CURSOR

FETCH NEXT FROM TAB_CURSOR
INTO @schema,
     @table,
     @object_id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
    DECLARE COL_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
    SELECT A.NAME
    FROM   sys.columns A
           INNER JOIN sys.types B
             ON A.SYSTEM_TYPE_ID = B.SYSTEM_TYPE_ID
    WHERE  OBJECT_ID = @object_id
           AND IS_COMPUTED = 0
           AND B.NAME IN ('char','nchar','nvarchar','varchar','text','ntext')

    OPEN COL_CURSOR

    FETCH NEXT FROM COL_CURSOR
    INTO @columnName

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
      BEGIN
        SET @sqlCommand = 'UPDATE ' + @schema + '.[' + @table + '] SET [' + @columnName
                           + '] = REPLACE(convert(nvarchar(max),[' + @columnName + ']),'''
                           + @stringToFind + ''',''' + @stringToReplace + ''')'

        SET @where = ' WHERE [' + @columnName + '] LIKE ''%' + @stringToFind + '%'''

        EXEC( @sqlCommand + @where)

        SET @count = @@ROWCOUNT

        IF @count > 0
          BEGIN
            PRINT @sqlCommand + @where
            PRINT 'Updated: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@count)
            PRINT '----------------------------------------------------'
          END

        FETCH NEXT FROM COL_CURSOR
        INTO @columnName
      END

    CLOSE COL_CURSOR
    DEALLOCATE COL_CURSOR

    FETCH NEXT FROM TAB_CURSOR
    INTO @schema,
         @table,
         @object_id
  END

CLOSE TAB_CURSOR
```

Comment: Perfect! This is golden. I've tweaked it a bit to meet my needs but it works perfectly! Thanks for your input.

Comment: @PeteFoulkes No problem. If this answered your question can you mark it as the solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
declare @charToReplace varchar(10) = 'char(13)' -- Carriage Return, CHAR(10) for line feed. Needs to be enclosed on quotes

select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) as ID
    , name as TableName
into #tables
from sys.tables

declare @Counter int = 0
declare @TotalTables int = (select COUNT(1) from #tables)

while @Counter < @TotalTables
begin

    declare @CurrTableName varchar(128) = (select TableName from #tables where ID = (@Counter + 1))
    declare @Columns nvarchar(4000) = ''
    declare @SQLQuery nvarchar(4000) = ''

    SELECT @Columns = COALESCE(@Columns + ',' , '') + c.name + ' = REPLACE(' + c.name + ', ' + @charToReplace + ', '''')'
    FROM SYS.tables t 
        INNER JOIN sys.columns c 
            ON C.object_id = t.object_id 
    where t.name = @CurrTableName 
        and c.user_type_id in (167, 231, 239)

    set @SQLQuery = 'UPDATE ' + @CurrTableName + ' SET ' + SUBSTRING(@Columns, 2, LEN(@Columns))

    print @SQLQuery -- You can change this to EXEC SP_EXECutesql @SQLQuery

    set @Counter += 1;

end

drop table #tables
```

I have not tested this, but I hope it can lead you to the solution that you are looking for.

NOTE: The `print @SQLQuery` should be replaced by `EXEC SP_EXECutesql @SQLQuery`, so it can make the changes on the DB.