# Is there a simple(r) way to REPLACE a character across all columns in one table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, replace, data-cleaning

There are ~10 different subquestions that could be answered here, but the main question is in the title. TLDR version: **I have a table like the example below and I want to replace all double quote marks across the whole table. Is there a simple way to do this?**

My solution using cursor seems fairly straightforward. I know there's some CURSOR hatred in the SQL Server community (bad runtime?). At what point (num rows and/or num columns) would CURSOR stink at this?

### Create Reproducible Example Table

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #example;
    CREATE TABLE #example (
       NumCol  INT
      ,CharCol  NVARCHAR(20)
      ,DateCol  NVARCHAR(100)
      );
      
    INSERT INTO #example VALUES
    (1, '"commas, terrible"',  '"2021-01-01 20:15:57,2021:04-08 19:40:50"'),
    (2, '"loadsrc,.txt"', '2020-01-01 00:00:05'),
    (3, '".txt,from.csv"','1/8/2021 10:14')
```

Right now, my identified solutions are:

1. Manually update for each column `UPDATE X SET CharCol = REPLACE(CharCol, '"','')`. Horribly annoying to do at any more than 2 columns IMO.
2. Use a CURSOR to update (similar to annoyingly complicated looking solution at [SQL Server- SQL Replace on all columns in all tables across an entire DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074051/sql-server-sql-replace-on-all-columns-in-all-tables-across-an-entire-db)

### REPLACE character using CURSOR

This gets a little convoluted with all the cursor-related script, but seems to work well otherwise.

```
-- declare variable to store colnames, cursor to filter through list, string for dynamic sql code
DECLARE  @colname   VARCHAR(10)
        ,@sql       VARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@namecursor CURSOR;

-- run cursor and set colnames and update table
SET @namecursor = CURSOR FOR SELECT ColName FROM #colnames
OPEN @namecursor;  
FETCH NEXT FROM @namecursor INTO @colname;  

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)  -- alt: WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN;  
        SET @sql = 'UPDATE #example SET '+@colname+' = REPLACE('+@colname+', ''"'','''')'
        EXEC(@sql); -- parentheses VERY important: EXEC(sql-as-string) NOT EXEC storedprocedure
        FETCH NEXT FROM @namecursor INTO @colname;  
    END;  
 
    CLOSE @namecursor;  
    DEALLOCATE @namecursor;  
    GO  

-- see results
SELECT * FROM #example
```

Subquestion: While I've seen it in our database elsewhere, for this particular example I'm opening a .csv file in Excel and exporting it as tab delimited. Is there a way to change the settings to export without the double quotes? If I remember correctly, `BULK INSERT` doesn't have a way to handle that or a way to handle importing a csv file with extra commas.

And yes, I'm going to pretend that I'm fine that there's a list of datetimes in the date column (necessitating varchar data type).

Comment: No, you pretty much got it.  Sometimes programming is just horribly annoying...  You could do things like dump the table to an external store and use something else to parse it out.  Or convert the whole table to JSON or XML and replace the characters in the single string then bring it back into your table.  But those are even more horribly annoying.  Or invest in IDE tools that'll help automate the task.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just dynamically build the SQL?

Presumably it's a one-time task you'd be doing so just run the below for your table, paste into SSMS and run. But if not you could build an automated process to execute it - better of course to properly sanitize when inserting the data though!

```
select 
'update <table> set ' +
String_Agg(QuoteName(COLUMN_NAME) + '=Replace(' + QuoteName(column_name) + ',''"'','''')',',')
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name='<table>' and TABLE_SCHEMA='<schema>' and data_type in ('varchar','nvarchar')
```

[example DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=180cb2d54794cb0e77fb8c7175a8bc33)

Answer (score 0):

You might try this approach, not fast, but easy to type (or generate).

```
SELECT NumCol = y.value('(NumCol/text())[1]','int')
      ,CharCol = y.value('(CharCol/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)')
      ,DateCol = y.value('(DateCol/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)')
FROM #example e
CROSS APPLY(SELECT e.* FOR XML PATH('')) A(x)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(REPLACE(A.x,'"','') AS XML)) B(y);
```

The idea in short:

- The first `APPLY` will transform all columns to a *root-less* XML.
- Without using `,TYPE` this will be of type `nvarchar(max)` implicitly
- The second `APPLY` will first replace any `"` in the whole text (which is one row actually) and cast this to XML.
- The `SELECT` uses `.value` to fetch the values **type-safe** from the XML.

**Update:** Just add `INTO dbo.SomeNotExistingTableName` right before `FROM` to create a new table with this data. This looks better than updating the existing table (might be a `#`-table too). I'd see this as a *staging* environment...

Good luck, messy data is always a pain in the neck :-)